# How can I dynamically add controllers to the app.module() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in AngularJS and I have made a function that takes in some parameters and pass them to a method of angularjs. I'm trying to figure out if this work using console.log but it does not print anything on console. It just doesn't work.

What is preventing me from passing the parameters (the dinamically created controllers) to be appended to the angular module variable?

this is the fragment of JS code:

```
app.controller('mainController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {.....

   //.... a lot of code...

  function createControllers(ControllerName, tab) {      
      app.controller(ControllerName, function (
          $scope,
          $rootScope,
          $http,

          ) {    
            console.log(ControllerName);
            init($scope, $rootScope, tab);
            obtenerParametros($http);
            watch($scope);
            guardarParametros($scope, $rootScope, tab);
            EditarParametros($scope, $rootScope, "Correcciones");
            limpiarParametro($scope, tab);
            eliminarParametro($scope, $rootScope, tab);
           SeleccionarParametro($scope, $rootScope);    
           mostrarFormatoPorDefecto($scope);
            if (ControllerName === 'GeneralController') {
                console.log('yes, Im the first');
            }   
        });
   }

  createControllers("GeneralController", "General");
  createControllers("ParametrosController", "CEMS");    
  createControllers("CorreccionesController", "Correcciones");
  createControllers("CilindrosController", "Cilindros");
  createControllers("EquiposController", "Equipos");
  createControllers("DPController", "DP");
  createControllers("MPController", "MP");
```

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS framework operates in two phases: the `config` phase and the `run` phase. Controllers can only be added during the `config` phase. Once the `run` phase starts, the app can not change its configuration, including adding additional controllers, directives, filters, services, etc.

To add controllers to the app module in the `config` phase:

```
app.config(["$controllerProvider", function ($controllerProvider) {

  //.... a lot of code...

  function createConstructor(ControllerName, tab) {      
     function controllerConstructor($scope, $rootScope, $http) {    
        console.log(ControllerName);
        init($scope, $rootScope, tab);
        obtenerParametros($http);
        watch($scope);
        //...
        mostrarFormatoPorDefecto($scope);
        if (ControllerName === 'GeneralController') {
            console.log('yes, Im the first');
        }   
     }
     controllerConstructor.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$http"];
     return controllerConstructor;
   }

   function register(controllerName, tab) {
       var constructorFn = createConstructor(controllerName, tab);
       $controllerProvider.register(controllerName, constructorFn);
   } 

   register("GeneralController", "General");
   register("ParametrosController", "CEMS");    
   register("CorreccionesController", "Correcciones");
   register("CilindrosController", "Cilindros");
   register("EquiposController", "Equipos");
   register("DPController", "DP");
   register("MPController", "MP");
}])
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $controllerProvider Provider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)